# Linux skb packet count header and metadata

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, skb

Could not find any info about this header at the end of Skb and about this metadata

So it seems it is user controlled and should be checked for bounds

```
static int ax88179_rx_fixup(struct usbnet *dev, struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    struct sk_buff *ax_skb;
    int pkt_cnt;
    u32 rx_hdr;
    u16 hdr_off;
    u32 *pkt_hdr;

    /* At the end of the SKB, there's a header telling us how many packets
     * are bundled into this buffer and where we can find an array of
     * per-packet metadata (which contains elements encoded into u16).
     */
    if (skb->len < 4)
        return 0;
    skb_trim(skb, skb->len - 4);
    rx_hdr = get_unaligned_le32(skb_tail_pointer(skb));
    pkt_cnt = (u16)rx_hdr;
    hdr_off = (u16)(rx_hdr >> 16);

    if (pkt_cnt == 0)
        return 0;

    /* Make sure that the bounds of the metadata array are inside the SKB
     * (and in front of the counter at the end).
     */
    if (pkt_cnt * 2 + hdr_off > skb->len)
        return 0;
```

Can somebody point to code in Kernel or references describing it?

Comment: I think you may be misinterpreting something that is device specific (i.e. an ASIX 88172 device will bundle single/multiple RX packets this way), with something that is generally true for a Linux netdev. This is the former.

Comment: So is this AXIS 88172 specific: `At the end of the SKB, there's a header telling us how many packets are bundled into this buffer and where we can find an array of per-packet metadata (which contains elements encoded into u16).`?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes (also ASIX 88179, since I apparently mistyped above). When this device provides RX data, it apparently appends trailing metadata for the contained packets. Other devices may use similar framing schemes.

Answer (score 2):

USB Ethernet devices don't have hardware framing support, so have their own schemes to do framing by inserting extra bytes in the packet. The tx_fixup and rx_fixup are provided to do that. Some of the schemes are described here: http://www.linux-usb.org/usbnet